# How to generate complex sound on Android?

Tags: android, audio

I need to generate complex sound with few frequences (superposition) on Android in real-time. How can i do it using Android SDK (preferred) or NDK?

It seems that using ToneGenerator is not flexible enough.
Recording AudioTrack with generated sound data and playing it seems to be the right direction, but i need it in real-time and recording and playing seems to be not real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from the book "Pro Android Media" by Shawn Van Every:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AudioSynthesis extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button startSound;
    Button endSound;

￼AudioSynthesisTask audioSynth;
boolean keepGoing = false;
float synth_frequency = 440; // 440 Hz, Middle A

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startSound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StartSound);
    startSound.setOnClickListener(this);
    endSound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.EndSound);
    endSound.setOnClickListener(this);
    endSound.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    keepGoing = false;
    endSound.setEnabled(false);
    startSound.setEnabled(true);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == startSound) {
        keepGoing = true;
        audioSynth = new AudioSynthesisTask();
        audioSynth.execute();
        endSound.setEnabled(true);
        startSound.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (v == endSound) {
        keepGoing = false;
        endSound.setEnabled(false);
        startSound.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

private class AudioSynthesisTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final int SAMPLE_RATE= 11025;
        int minSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            minSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    audioTrack.play();
    short[] buffer = new short[minSize];
    float angular_frequency =
       (float)(2*Math.PI) * synth_frequency / SAMPLE_RATE;
    float angle = 0;
    while (keepGoing) {
         for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
         {
             buffer[i] = (short)(Short.MAX_VALUE * ((float) Math.sin(angle)));
             angle += angular_frequency;
         }
         audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }
    return null;
}
} }
```